# How to add Public field to case comment creation layout?

Tags: case, page-layout, standard-objects, case-comment

I can't find the `Public` checkbox on the `CaseComment` creation page. How can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public actually refers to making it available to the case contact(customer) on a Customer Portal/Self-Service Portal. Internally, if a user can see the case, they can see the case comments.